# Need to know how to fix z-index when resizing browser to a smaller size

Tags: css

I hope someone can assist with my issue.  When I use Z-index in a desktop window every image or slider overlaps the way it should look.  When I resize my browser to the resolution of a mobile device, it breaks up the Z-index, so what I see is my images with spacing in them.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't expect to receive any constructive answer without providing any piece of html with the problem you're having. There is no magic.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to remind you that z-index works only on explicitly positioned HTML elements, like:

```
position:absolute;
position:fixed;
position:relative;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it doesn't have anything to do with z-index if it was working well on the desktop. It can be literally anything. But the z-index is probably not the problem because the z-index doesn't change with the window size.

The only thing that is important to understand with the z-index is that you can group them. And that the opacity is actually creating a z-index group too. So if you're chaging the opacity of an element, the z-index may change and some element may have a different rendering order.

That said, if you have paddings or media queries that change some values in css. (responsive css) Then it's possible that with smaller window size, there is a css query that will modify paddings or even opacities or even Z-index! But who knows what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your page in chrome with Desktop-sized browser window, right-click on one of the images, click `inspect element`, search for any `z-index` css rules (on the right-side of the window), find any rules, which determine the `z-index`, then resize the window to the size of a mobile phone and do the same. You will find this way what rules determine the `z-index` and you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parent container should be in:

```
position: absolute;
```

While the element with z-index should be in:

```
position: relative;
```

You can also add position:

```
position: relative;
top: 1em;
right: 1em;
```